# Why the masked image is covered by the colour of the mask?

Tags: javascript, mask, createjs, animate-cc

I am using createJS to mask a picture, and the mask will be drawn by user.

Since the mask will be updated when user dragging, I used mouseAlphaMaskFilter with image caching to achieve the mask effect. Unfortunately it results in an unexpected way. The picture is covered by stroke colour and the picture only being visible when the stroke colour is semi-transparent.

[Here is the on going testing](https://codepen.io/ringoma/pen/XGwpeY)
(Please drag in the canvas to see its result)

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

var shape, bmp, oldX, oldY, size, color;
var stageWidth = 550;
var stageHeight = 400;

mycolor = createjs.Graphics.getRGB(255, 255, 255, .5);

shape = new createjs.Shape();
bmp = new createjs.Bitmap("https://ocdn.eu/pulscms-transforms/1/dZtktkqTURBXy8xNTI0OTU1NWRlNDMyZDNiMjcwZDY2YjVlODJjNDRiNC5qcGVnkZUCzQMWAMLD");
shape.cache(0,0,550,400);
bmp.filters = [new createjs.AlphaMaskFilter(shape.cacheCanvas)];
bmp.cache(0,0,550,400);

stage.on("stagemousemove", function (evt) {
    if (oldX) {
        shape.graphics.beginStroke(color)
        .setStrokeStyle(size, "round")
        .moveTo(oldX, oldY)
        .lineTo(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);
    }
    oldX = evt.stageX;
    oldY = evt.stageY;
    shape.updateCache();
    bmp.updateCache();
    stage.update();
})

stage.on("stagemouseup", function (event) {
    color = mycolor;
});

stage.on("stagemousedown", function (event) {
    color = mycolor;
    size = 20;
});

stage.on("stagemouseup", function (event) {
    color = "";
});

stage.addChild(bmp);
stage.addChild(shape);
stage.update();
```

[Expected result as an usual mask by createJS](https://codepen.io/ringoma/pen/qvGROM)
(But this method `bmp.mask = shape` only works when the mask is unchanged.)

Sorry for my bad explanation above.
It's grateful if any helps could lead me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A shape mask does not need to be cached. You can accomplish the same thing using just a shape as the mask. This means you don't need to cache the bitmap either. Further, masks should not be added to the stage.

The AlphaMaskFilter is better if you have various levels of opacity you want to apply.

Here is a super simple version of your codepen: https://codepen.io/lannymcnie/pen/drEBvw?editors=0010

```
var shape = new createjs.Shape();
shape.graphics.drawCircle(200,200,100);
bmp.mask = shape;
```

Cheers,